# Android Retrofit Dynamic Endpoint URL

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

Is there a way to provide a dynamic endpoint urls to the retrofit library.
I know that it would be difficult or impossible to modify the interfaces that retrofit uses to generate the implementation but is there another way.

For example can I dynamically change "/users/{user}/repos"

```
public interface GitHubService {
  @GET("/users/{user}/repos")
  List<Repo> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

The reason I would like to do that is because the api designers are providing a map of the enpoint urls and the client insist to use them so that when the api changes we won't need to release an update of the application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using absolute URLs with Retrofit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116395/using-absolute-urls-with-retrofit)

Answer (score 0):

I don't even know if it will work but I would try to do it in this way:

`listReposTemplateUrl()` returns template for current api with `{user}` to be replaced. Then you replace it with particular user and pass whole url with replaced `{user}` to the `listRepos()` call.

#### my api interface:

```
public interface MyApi {
    @GET("/apiTemplates/listRepos")
    String listReposTemplateUrl();

    @GET("/{listReposUrl}")
    List<Repo> listRepos(@Path("listReposUrl") String listReposUrl);
}
```

#### helper class:

```
class TemplateUrlFiller {
    public static String fillListRepos(String template, String user) {
        return template.replace("{user}", user);
    }
}
```

#### usage:

```
String user = "Bob";
String listReposTemplate = getMyApi().listReposTemplateUrl(); // "/users/{user}/repos" || "/giveMyRepos/{user}" || ...

List<Repo> = getMyApi().listRepos(TemplateUrlFiller.fillListRepos(listReposTemplate, user));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use that in the interface:

```
@GET("{id}.htm?ca=2_s")
    Call<ResponseBody> getAppartsDetailed(@Path(value = "id", encoded = true)String appartId);
```

the key is

> @Path(value = "id", encoded = true)

Then you will get

> yourBaseUrl/1164374459.htm?ca=2_s